# Why does mysql function now() sometimes return00:00:00?

Tags: mysql, database, time

I write several mysql commands like these:

```
insert into news_seeds values(1, 'http://www...', 0, 0, 60, now(), 10, now());
insert into news_seeds values(2, 'http://www...', 0, 0, 60, now()-10, 10, now()-2);
insert into news_seeds values(3, 'http://www...', 0, 0, 60, now()-20, 10, now()-4);
...
```

but i find sometimes now just returns 00:00:00, why?

Comment: Because sometimes it's midnight.

Comment: please show the table structure too -- we need to see the type(s) of the columns you're inserting.

Comment: I think, he is looking for something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549087/mysql-strange-result-when-subtracting-date-value-and-now

Answer (score 2):

`00:00:00` is midnight, to the second.

If it isn't midnight, you might be doing a `SET TIMESTAMP` before calling `NOW()`.